# Unable to use knex to create tables and send data to the database I had problems with associations between tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, database-design, knex.js

I'm trying to create three tables with knex, but I don't know if the way I'm trying to create them has changed since the last time I created it 3 years ago this way.
My user migration is this:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
    table.increments('id').primary()
    table.string('name').notNull()
    table.integer('age').notNull()
    table.string('city').notNull()
    table.string('email').notNull().unique()
    table.string('primary').notNull()
    table.timestamp('deletedAt')
    table.timestamp('updatedAt')
  });
};
exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
};
```

While the post migration is this:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('posts', table => {
    table.increments('id').primary()
    table.string('description').notNull()
    table.string('image_url', 1000).notNull()
    table.string('latitude').notNull()
    table.string('longitude').notNull()
    table.integer('userId').references('id')
      .inTable('users').notNull()
    table.timestamp('deletedAt')
    table.timestamp('updatedAt')
  });
};
exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('posts');
};
```

And my last table is the evaluations:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('evaluations', table => {
    table.inplements('id').primary()
    table.int('review').notNull()
    table.decimal('rate', (1,2)).notNull()
    table.integer('postId').references('id')
      .inTable('posts').notNull()
    table.integer('userId').references('id')
      .inTable('users').notNull()
    table.timestamp('deletedAt')
    table.timestamp('updatedAt')
  });
};
exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('evaluations');
};
```

When I run the command knex migrate:latest I create the users table and posts table in the database, but the evaluations table is not created and I get this error at the prompt:

```
migration file "20210902232536_create_posts_table.js" failed
migration failed with error: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_userid_foreign` foreign key (`userId`) references `users` (`id`) - Referencing column 'userId' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'posts_userid_foreign' are incompatible.
alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_userid_foreign` foreign key (`userId`) references `users` (`id`) - Referencing column 'userId' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'posts_userid_foreign' are incompatible.
Error: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_userid_foreign` foreign key (`userId`) references `users` (`id`) - Referencing column 'userId' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'posts_userid_foreign' are incompatible.
    at Packet.asError (F:\nodejs\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:722:17)
    at Query.execute (F:\nodejs\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
    at Connection.handlePacket (F:\nodejs\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (F:\nodejs\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (F:\nodejs\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\nodejs\test\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10
```

I'm not sure whay this is hapening with the association because I used to create it this same way before, but now it seems I don't have the id into the users table or into the posts table either I have
And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "consign": "^0.1.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "knex": "^0.95.10",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.0",
    "node-schedule": "^2.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help someone can give me

Answer (score 1):

Once that I had no unswears here, I had to find out where is the documentation of the knex lib so I saw that many things are different from 3 years ago, and after a long research I finally was able to solve this problem by myself:

My users migration is the same as before.

But the posts migration now had to be created this way:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('posts', table => {
  table.increments('id').primary()
  table.string('description').notNull()
  table.string('image_url', 1000).notNull()
  table.string('latitude').notNull()
  table.string('longitude').notNull()
  table.integer('userId').unsigned().notNullable()
    .references('id').inTable('users')
  table.timestamp('updatedAt')
  });
  };
  exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('posts');
  };
```

And the evaluations migration was set like this:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('evaluations', table => {
  table.increments('id').primary()
  table.integer('review').notNull()
  table.decimal('rate', (1,2)).notNull()
  table.integer('postId').unsigned().notNullable()
    .references('id').inTable('posts')
  table.integer('userId').unsigned().notNullable()
    .references('id').inTable('users')
  table.timestamp('deletedAt')
  });
  };
  exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('evaluations');
  };
```

If someone else faces this trouble with this new way to create foreignkey into a migration using knex, this was the way I found.